# DNS records to have website on different server

Tags: email, domain, hosting, domain-name-system

I've been asked by my client to set up their website on a different server to where their domain currently points to. They have their email and the domain name hosted with one company at the moment including a small amount of web space that came with their email account (Had no PHP or MySQL or anything so that why I'm now hosting their website). Only issue is, when I went and changed their Zone file DNS records it was pointing to my server correctly but it broke their email as well. I havent had much experience with DNS Records and I can't, after Googling almost non-stop for 2 days, find a solution.

The current Zonefile is below. I've changed the IP address and the domain name for privacy reasons.

```
example.com.au.          86400 IN TXT   "google-site-verification=dvMaqYAUGx_lDAu1ZqzexAleM75znUU-GQ1AJLvA41w"
example.com.au.          86400 IN NS    ns32b.ssggrp-wc.com.
example.com.au.          86400 IN NS    ns32a.ssggrp-wc.com.
www.example.com.au.      300   IN MX    150 mail.example.com.au.
example.com.au.          300   IN MX    100 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
example.com.au.          300   IN MX    100 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
example.com.au.          300   IN MX    150 mail.example.com.au.
example.com.au.          300   IN MX    50 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
example.com.au.          300   IN MX    75 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
example.com.au.          300   IN MX    75 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
www.example.com.au.      86400 IN A     205.123.456.789
webmail.example.com.au.  86400 IN A     205.123.456.789
smtp.example.com.au.     86400 IN A     205.123.456.789
example.com.au.          86400 IN A     205.123.456.789
mail.example.com.au.     86400 IN A     205.123.456.789
ftp.example.com.au.      86400 IN A     205.123.456.789
cp.example.com.au.       86400 IN A     205.123.456.789
```

I tried changing the "www.example.com.au" and "example.com.au" 'A' records to my IP address and it worked for the website but it broke their email. I can't do it again and get it wrong as they can't afford to not have email functioning while it propagates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embarrassing but I better close off this question. The issues was with my server as I had set up the domain name of my client as a parked domain name. When I sent email using my server it looked for the email accounts locally (I forgot this happened) but they were hosted on different servers. Their email hadn't broken as I'd thought. Changing the two A records as I originally described did in fact make the necessary redirects.

Answer (score 4):

You are using Google Apps for domains I see, however, you got a subdomain `mail`,`webmail` and `smtp` pointing to something else then a google-server.

One of these should be a `CNAME` for the webmail application pointing to `ghs.google.com.`

Then you also have an `MX` record for `www.example.com.au.` which implies you have user using email like this: `user@www.example.com.au`. That seems a bit odd. Are you hosting the email servers for a subdomain yourself?

Also, while you are doing changes to various records, it's adviced to lower the TTL values to make the propagation go faster in case of changes.

Comment: +1. Poster and domain setup look clueless to me, too. Omething is fishy.

Comment: Thanks Bart De Vos. I was thrown into the deep end with this one as the person who was handling my clients website and email went out of business. I was only meant to be handling the website design and handing over the files, but they needed someone to take over the whole system. I can see that the records are a mess, and I have no idea why they were made like that either. Thanks for your help so far. I'll do some more digging and se if I can find out how their system is setup. Unfortunately I cant contact the person who set it all up as they have kind of 'fallen off the radar' so to speak.

Comment: Start by making a list of all the services they are using that need some form of DNS and their IP's. Add it to the opening post and i'll see what I can do.

Comment: +1  It would probably be beneficial to go through the Google Apps documentation to help you understand how things should be set up so you can compare it with how it is currently configured: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=48090.